# Is there something like logcat for python?

Tags: python, logcat

I was wondering if there was something similar to Android's logcat but for Python. I haven't had much luck in my search for this.

Edit:

I very much understand that python is not an operating system. I'm looking for something that hooks into the debugger with similar features to logcat. I know about python's logging library but it is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a standard logging module called `logging`. This is used frequently in Python applications and systems, including by many other Python modules, etc. jabaldonedo is correct in that Python is a programming language not an Operating System, so its approach to logging is going to be different.  However, the `logging` module is probably closest to what you're looking for.

Here's a link to recipes relating to how its used:  https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: I'm well aware of logging and the fact that python is not an operating system. I was looking for something with the same features as logcat.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing things, logcat is as defined in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) as a tool for collecting operating system messages, it has nothing to do with programming.

> The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug output. Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers, which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command

So obviously there is nothing similar in Python, just because Python is not a OS, it is a programming language.

Don't mix things! Android is the operating system, you write apps in a programming language like Java.

If you want to generate logging messages, then Python gives you the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library.

Comment: I don't see what I'm confusing. I want something that hooks into a debugger (for example pydev) and has ways to filter out different messages from different parts of the system. This would happen through some type of import like pdb and I would set the log messages from there which would be output to the 'pylogcat' when appropriate. I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you, anyway. If you are looking for a GUI tool or addon to any IDE that allows you to filter logging messages, I don't know any, but in any case, if you want to print logging messages, use the logging library.

Comment: No, I'm well aware of the logging library. It's just not powerful enough for what I need. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: @jabaldonedo - Logcat is a developer tool provided by Android, which interactively displays the log file (allowing filtering etc). So yes, obviously it is related to programming and used (all the time) by programmers. And it would be very helpful to have such a tool for other environments, too.